# Prevent child div from overflowing parent div

Tags: css, overflow

I have a parent div containing a header section and a body section. The parent div has a maximum height, but no minimum height.

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/1o79a6nc/2/

```css
#cont {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 50%;
}
#body {
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#head {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='cont'>
  <div id='head'>
    <div>Head</div>
  </div>
  <div id='body'>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the body to only expand so that it fits inside the parent (including the padding), and then apply scroll bars when necessary.

As the example shows, I have tried `overflow-y: auto`, however this is not working as I have intended.

Edit: I want scroll bars to only appear on the body, so that the head section and the parent bottom padding are always visible.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You could simply set the container to flexbox.

```
#cont {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 50%;
  display: flex; /*added*/
  flex-direction: column; /*added*/
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtta8wx8/)**

```css
#cont {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 50%;
  display: flex; /*added*/
  flex-direction: column; /*added*/
}
#body {
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  flex: 1; /* added */
}
#head {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='cont'>
  <div id='head'>
    <div>Head</div>
  </div>
  <div id='body'>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
    <div>Body</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another option would be using CSS table, some extra HTML code is needed. And `max-height` doesn't work with table layout, so use `height` instead.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uza0uk3d/)**

```css
#cont {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 50%;
  display: table;
}
#head,
#body {
  display: table-row;
}
#head > div,
#body > div {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
}
#body > div {
  height: 100%;
}
#body > div > div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#body {
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#head {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id='cont'>
  <div id='head'>
    <div>Head</div>
  </div>
  <div id='body'>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>Body</div>
        <div>Body</div>
        <div>Body</div>
        <div>Body</div>
        <div>Body</div>
        <div>Body</div>
        <div>Body</div>
        <div>Body</div>
        <div>Body</div>
        <div>Body</div>
        <div>Body</div>
        <div>Body</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

This solution worked for me and its display the vertical scrollbar only in child div.

```
.parent
{
    height : 300px ; //for example
    overflow: hidden;
}  

.child  
{   
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: No, the child is bigger than it should if there is another child

Answer (score 2):

i updated your jsfiddle check it out

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1o79a6nc/3/)

```
#cont {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 50%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#body {
  background-color: blue;

}
#head {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: That _mostly_ works for this example, but will not work in the general case. The header might take up 50% of the available height, for example.