# Aligning divs within a div

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend

I am trying to create front end in angular based on a design given. My design looks like

[image]

My code

.html

```
 <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-bewteen start" fxLayoutGap="12px" class="side_start">
        <div fxFlex="12" class="second_bar">
            Side
        </div>
        <div fxFlex="88" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-bewteen" fxLayoutGap="12px">
            <div [ngClass]="['third_bar_1']">
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-bewteen start" >
                        <div fxFlex="7" class="zone">
                                Zone Thermal Comfort
                            </div>
                            <div fxFlex="5" class="temp">
                                <p>TEMP</p>
                                <p>37 deg</p>
                            </div>
                            <div fxFlex="5" class="hum">
                                <p>RH %</p>
                                <p>25</p>
                            </div>
                            <div fxFlex="7" class="comfort_index">
                                48
                            </div>

                            <div fxFlex="8" class="comfort_meter">
                                <img class="meter_img" src="../../assets/Temp Hot-01-01.png">
                            </div>
                            <div fxFlex = 7 class="energy_box">
                                ENERGY USAGE
                            </div>
                            <div fxFlex = 7 class="energy_reading">
                                30%
                            </div>
                            <div fxFlex="8" class="energy_meter">
                                <img src="../../assets/Energy Gauge 10-01.png" >
                            </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
            <div [ngClass]="['third_bar_2']">
                second
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

.css

```
.second_bar{
    background-color: #6390c3;
    height: calc(100vh - 200px);  
}

.third_bar_1{
    border:1px solid red;
    background-color: white;
    height: 60px;
}

.zone {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /* font-color: #5d6d88; */
    background-color: #f1cd86;
    text-align: center;
    height: 71%;
}

.temp {
    background-color: #73d9fa ;
    text-align: center;
}

.hum{
    background-color:  #73fac5;
    text-align: center;
}

.comfort_index{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f1cd86;
    height: 71%;
}

.comfort_meter{
    margin-left: 1.8%;
    align-content: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.meter_img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /* object-fit: contain; */
}

.energy_box{
    margin-left: 27%;
    background-color: #f1cd86;
}

.energy_reading{
    background-color: #6390c3;
}

.energy_meter{
    margin-left: 1.8%;
}

.third_bar_2{   
    border:1px solid red;
    height: calc(100vh - 355px);
}
```

what i developed looks like
[image]

I am trying to align my divs to center within a div, but its not happening. I have seen other posts and tried several things like display:flex, align:center, many other things, but I was not able to make it look like design. Can some one help me  with this.

Comment: This colud be a possible duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066204/prevent-child-div-from-overflowing-parent-div

Comment: maybe you should try to do it without fxFlex? Using only css flex. Just thinking that your using both css flex and the flex-layout. I can see there might be some ovelapping issues when your using both. If your choose only css you will get less attributes on the html elements. You would only need to use the class attribute. Is it something I missed? Do you need to use flex-layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here check this out.

https://codepen.io/Cleee/pen/mdbOOKZ

I used float for the columns and the flexbox for centering the content inside the boxes. Added also a few container wrapper. But you just had do define the width and the height of the elements. I used absolute values. You also can use relative values like percent for responsive layouts.

Hope this helps.

```
body {
  font-family:Roboto;
  font-size:12px;
}
.zone, .comfort_index, .energy_box, .energy_reading {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /* font-color: #5d6d88; */
    background-color: #f1cd86;
    text-align: center;
    height: 71%;
  justify-content:center;
}
.second_bar { width: 200px;
float:left;}
.contentWrapper {
  width:calc(100% - 200px);
  float:right;
}
.secondContentWrap {
  border:1px solid #ff0000;
  min-height:300px;
  clear:both;
}
.zone, .comfort_index, .temp , .hum{
  width:86px;
  height:60px;
  float:left;
}
.temp {}
.temp p, .hum p {
  height:30px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.temp p:nth-of-type(2), .hum p:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color:#639FE5;
  color:#fff;
  border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15)
}
.hum {}
.hum p {}
.hum p:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-left:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-right:0;
}
.comfort_index {}
.outterWrapperOne {
  width:344px;
  float:left;
}
.outterWrapperTwo {
  float:left;
  width: calc(100% - 344px)
}
.comfort_meter, .energy_box , .energy_reading, .energy_meter {
  float:left;
  height:60px;
}

.comfort_meter {
  width:45px;
  height;60px;
}
.comfort_meter img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
.energy_box {
  margin-left:27%;
   width:86px;
}
.energy_reading {
  width:86px;
  background-color: #6390c3;
  color: #fff;
}
.energy_meter {}
.energy_meter img {}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Only that there was no spacing around, everything else is fine. I will try to figure out the spacing.

Comment: Yeah i know but i was sure you can figure it out. If not let me know! :) Mark as the correct answer and upvote would be great. :D

Comment: Hey , can you help me with that spacing, how do I do it for all the divs?

Comment: with margin-left:X PX / % and margin-right

Comment: The Updatet Pen. I added a few html container for a better dom structur. anything else is just basic css setup. Do you know how to format the text?https://codepen.io/Cleee/pen/mdbOOKZ